# Replace Hard Drive for an SSD - Suggestion?

Tags: ssd, hard-disk, osx

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012), and I'd like to speed up my computer. To do this, I'd like to change my Hard Drive for an SSD (with approximately 500 GB memory). I thought buying an SSD PCI Express (those used at Apple), but I don't know if this what is best.

**Question :** Could anyone be able to suggest me a very good SSD for my computer?

**Question :** What is the better choice between an SSD PCI Express and the [OWC
480GB Mercury Extreme® Pro 6G SSD 2.5" Serial-ATA 7mm Solid State Drive](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/SSD7P6G480/) ?

Comment: Don't just re-ask your question because it was closed; it was closed for a reason. The yellow box under the original question tells you why; use that to edit and improve your existing question to the point where it can be reopened.